# how to get line spacing greater than one and half spacing and less than double space

Tags: line-spacing

Does anyone know how to get line spacing in a paragraph to be greater than one and half spacing and less than double spacing?
I tried `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{value}` but it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
\usepackage{setspace}
```

Then for the document, in the preamble

```
\setstretch{1.75}
```

or for part of it, in the body

```
\begin{spacing}{1.75}% assuming standard spacing is < 1.75
  ...
\end{spacing}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `\selectfont` after changing `\baselinestretch`. Also, if you want to apply it to a region, you can use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` (or `{` and `}` if you prefer). For example:

```
\begingroup \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.75}\selectfont
This starts a new paragraph.

\endgroup
```

IMPORTANT: Please note that a new paragraph (empty line) is required before `\endgroup` for the change to be effective.

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your answer slightly. Please take a look to see how I formatted the code as the `<code>...</code>` do not get you suitable syntax highlighting, whereas the block indentation does.

Comment: However, note that `setspace` is recommended for this as it takes various precautions which are absent from the brute-force approach :-).

Comment: Surely. Thanks for the editing. I agree that `setspace` is a recommended solution.