# Is there any 1.75 spacing setting in latex?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I am using a template from overleaf.

I am using

```
\usepackage{setspace}
```

and

```
%\doublespacing
\singlespacing
```

But i feel doubespacing too large, single spacing too narrow.
Is there a way to set 1.5 spacing?

This is one of the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %disable auto indentation

% $ \| \underaccent{\tilde}{\tilde{x}} \| $
% \doublespacing
\singlespacing
% This is my $\|\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}\|$
Testing Testing
$\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2, \space\widetilde{x_1}^2, \space\widetilde{x_2}, ..., 1}$
Second sentences
$\hat{\undertilde{\widetilde{x}}}$ $=$ $\sqrt{0^2,\space\widetilde{x_1}^2,\space\widetilde{x_2}^2, ..., 1}$

First formular
 \[ y = a + b1 \]
 \[ c = a + b2  \]

  \[ y = a + b1 and c = a + b2  \]


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\onehalfspacing`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks. How about 1.75 spacing? I found 1.5 spacing is a bit small also. `2.0: double spacing` is too wide.

Comment: `\onehalfspacing` is short for `\setstretch{1.25}`. Just play with that value until you have the line spacing you like.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [how to get line spacing greater than one and half spacing and less than double space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328300/134144)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks. it works.